# Cannot save a .docm file after assigning a value to a particular document.variable

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a file with a macro that was originally created as a `.doc` file. If I try to save it as a `.docm` or `.dotm` file, it will not save.  No error message, but the file doesn't get saved.

If I remove the module; or save it as a `.docx` file, it will save.

If I

- open the `.docx` file
- import or copy/paste the previous macro into a regular module
- run the macro

again, it cannot be saved as a `.docm`

If I remove the module, I can save it as a `.docm`

Or, even with the macro present and having been run, I can save it as a `.doc` file.

So it seems there might be something in the macro that, after having run, creates a file that cannot be saved as a `.docm` but could still be saved as a `.doc` file.

The macro examines some custom properties of the document that are manually entered.  It computes a variety of document variables which are used in fields throughout the document, and then updates those fields.

By using breakpoints, It seems that when the code assigns a value to the `Document.Variable` `"sign"`, the document can no longer be saved.  That is a date field, but there are other date fields in the document that don't cause this problem.

The code.text for the particular fields:

```
docvariable "sign" \@ "MMMM, yyyy" \*upper \* MERGEFORMAT 
docvariable "sign" \@ "d" \* OrdText \*upper\* MERGEFORMAT
```

The macro code (in a regular module):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update()
    Dim prop As DocumentProperty
    Dim area As Double, rent As Double, start As Date, tend As Date, notice As Date, term As Long, Sign As Date
    Dim annual As Double, annualcents As Double, monthly As Double, monthlycents As Long
    Dim var As Variables

'get Document Properties
For Each prop In ThisDocument.CustomDocumentProperties
    If prop.Name = "area" Then area = prop.Value
    If prop.Name = "rent" Then rent = prop.Value
    If prop.Name = "start" Then start = Int(prop.Value)
    If prop.Name = "term" Then term = prop.Value
    If prop.Name = "sigDate" Then Sign = Int(prop.Value)
Next prop

    annual = area * rent
    annualcents = 100 * (annual - Int(annual))
    monthly = annual / 12
    monthlycents = 100 * (monthly - Int(monthly))
    tend = DateAdd("yyyy", term, start)
    tend = DateAdd("d", -1, tend)
    notice = DateAdd("m", -4, tend)

Set var = ThisDocument.Variables
    var("area").Value = area
    var("rent").Value = rent
    var("start").Value = start
    var("term").Value = term

    'if this line is not run or
    'if this document variable is deleted,
    'the file will save as expected
    var("sign").Value = Sign


    var("annual").Value = annual
    var("annualcents").Value = annualcents
    var("monthly").Value = monthly
    var("monthlycents").Value = monthlycents
    var("tend").Value = tend
    var("notice").Value = notice

ThisDocument.Fields.Update

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Document.Variable "sign"` is used by Word to indicate that a valid digital signature has been applied to the code project.

Choose a different name for your variable such as "sigDate"

Comment: Thank you for the solution.  I searched for things like "ms-word reserved words", and found nothing.  I looked up `Sign` and found it listed as a method of the `Signature` object.  I changed the name in the `CustomDocumentProperties`, but I never changed it in the `Variables` list.  This has been driving me crazy for years!